# Excel VBA - Sub or Function not defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a compile error on this method and I can't figure out why. I'm getting the "Sub or Function not define" error.  Its probably something silly, but escaping me nontheless.
Thanks in advance.

```
Public Function GetReportDate(dept As String) As String

    Dim dateOut As String   'this will be the returned value from the method
    Dim dateIn As String    'this is the date retrieved from the report

    Dim MonthNum As String
    Dim Temp As String      'this variable stores that date that will be manipulated
    Dim StartEnd(1 To 4, 1 To 4) As String
    Dim Period As String
    Dim Year As Integer

    'select the date string
    Select Case dept
    Case "Min and AMF": Cells(2, 2).Select
    Case Else: Cells(2, 1).Select
    End Select

    Selection.Font.Bold = True

    'store the month, day and year string to the array
    dateIn = ActiveCell.Value
    Temp = dateIn
    StartEnd(1, 1) = Mid(Temp, 1, 2)    '1st month
    StartEnd(1, 2) = Mid(Temp, 14, 2)   '2nd month
    StartEnd(2, 1) = Mid(Temp, 4, 2)    '1st day
    StartEnd(2, 2) = Mid(Temp, 17, 2)   '2nd day
    StartEnd(3, 1) = Mid(Temp, 7, 4)    '1st year

    'assign to two var
    MonthNum = StartEnd(1, 2)
    Year = StartEnd(3, 1)

    ' change the month format for the 1st month
    Select Case StartEnd(1, 1)
        Case "01": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Jan"
        Case "02": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Feb"
        Case "03": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Mar"
        Case "04": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Apr"
        Case "05": StartEnd(1, 1) = "May"
        Case "06": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Jun"
        Case "07": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Jul"
        Case "08": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Aug"
        Case "09": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Sep"
        Case "10": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Oct"
        Case "11": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Nov"
        Case "12": StartEnd(1, 1) = "Dec"
    End Select

    ' change the month format for the 2nd month
    Select Case StartEnd(1, 2)
        Case "01": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Jan"
        Case "02": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Feb"
        Case "03": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Mar"
        Case "04": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Apr"
        Case "05": StartEnd(1, 2) = "May"
        Case "06": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Jun"
        Case "07": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Jul"
        Case "08": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Aug"
        Case "09": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Sep"
        Case "10": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Oct"
        Case "11": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Nov"
        Case "12": StartEnd(1, 2) = "Dec"
    End Select


    'Change the Date Format After the Min Qem has been executed
    'If dept = "Min and AMF" Then

        ' the 1st and 2nd month are equal
        If StartEnd(1, 1) = StartEnd(1, 2) Then
            ' find the type of report
            If StartEnd(2, 2) - StartEnd(2, 1) <= 7 Then
                Period = "Week"
            Else
                 Period = "Month"
            End If

            ' change the report period to the right format
            ActiveCell = Period & " of " & StartEnd(1, 1) & " " & StartEnd(2, 1) & " " _
                    & "to" & " " & StartEnd(2, 2) & " " & Year
        Else     ' the 1st and 2nd month are NOT equal
            If 30 - StartEnd(2, 1) + StartEnd(2, 2) >= 20 Then
                Period = "Month"
            Else
                Period = "Week"
            End If


    'change the header of the report to represt the period
                ActiveCell = Period & " of " & StartEnd(1, 1) & " " & StartEnd(2, 1) _
                        & " " & "to" & " " & StartEnd(1, 2) & " " & StartEnd(2, 2) _
                        & " " & Year
            End If

        'return the dateout
        dateOut = Temp
        GetReportDate = dateOut
    End Function
```

When i call the method this is what I'm using.

```
CurReport = GetReportName(sDept)
```

Comment: Dammit!! I'm an idiot, calling the wrong function...its just doing what I'm telling it to do.

Answer (score 2):

There's a mismatch between what you are calling and the function you have defined. `Date` and `Name` are not the same.

```
Public Function GetReportDate(dept As String) As String
        GetReportDate = dateOut
    End Function
```

is not going to be called by

```
CurReport = GetReportName(sDept)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed the same thing. Changed it all is good.